# graph api facebook user uploads video

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I just created a Facebook App and I want to: 
1. user logs in --> browse and select video --> upload to own wall.

I have a bit of code from Facebook Dev. examples, but I get an error.
After reading and error nature, I can imagine my problem is somewhere here:

CODE:

`$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) 
    . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret 
    . "&code=" . $code . "&type=client_cred";`

`$access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);`

ERORR:
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}

any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the access token you have isn't valid for the current user.

Must first redirect to FB to get the token using your app id:

```
$dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=".YOUR APP ID."&redirect_uri=".urlencode(YOUR CALLBACK URL).'&scope=email,publish_stream';
```

**Updated**

It's likely that you haven't request enough permissions, see the scope parameter, you will need the have permission to publish_stream in order to post a user story.

After you have this code, you need to grab the actual app access token by making arequest to a URL which is something like:

```
$token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={APP ID}&redirect_uri=".urlencode(CALLBACK)."&client_secret={SECRET}&code=$code";
```

Comment: hi, thanks for reply. i'm using this:

`if(empty($code)) {
   $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
     . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) 
     . "&scope=publish_stream";
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
}`

Comment: made all changes :/ but still the same. thanks for indicating to check permissions. seems like `publish_actions` is for uploading photo and videos. but still, same error: 

"message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500

Comment: ok, works fine now with code from dev example. don't know why. but thanks! got to know difference between `publish_actions` and `publish_steam`.